# .NET Modify file metadata such as File Version

Tags: c#, .net, file, version, metadata

We all know how to get the File Version in C#:

```
var info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(FilePath);
Console.WriteLine($"File Version: {info.FileVersion}");
```

How can you set/modify that information on any arbitrary file.

*NOTE* please don't refer to the assembly info, this is for **any** file, not the resulting exe/dll from compilation of the C# file. I.e. how do you open an arbitrary file and set/change the FileVersion/ProductVersion or any other metadata on it? (even if possible via C/unsafe code it is still acceptable).

Comment: Is the file signed?

Comment: No, unsigned, not encrypted, standard file

Comment: Hmm... product version is editable with a hex editor... not sure about file version though... if it isn't signed there is a small chance it can be done relatively easy.... although it shouldn't be easy. Maybe you can check the rosalyn compiler's source.

Comment: Hmm...it seems [FileVersion is `readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_FileVersionInfo_FileVersion), so unless it's "touched".

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it in c#. But for c++ this may help https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13355/Modification-of-Version-Information-Resources-in-C. You can try to replicate in unmanaged c#

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this won't work with signed files.

---

Use a hex editor or Visual Studio, to open the file in a Binary editor.

Search for the phrase:

> VS_VERSION_INFO

(note, in 16-bit, so it's shown as V.S._.V.  .. etc.)

Search and edit the metadata property you want to edit.

---

Windows itself also has a build in option to modify some metadata, referred as personal info:

[image]

Click the "remove prperties..."

[image]

---

Not sure about the file info though, it might be tougher since it's a bigger security risk when it's overwritten that easy.

Comment: what if the file version does not exist on that file? how do you add it?

Comment: what kind of file is it?

Comment: zip/tar file or any other archive